# Pre-Select UIPickerView in xcode

Tags: xcode, select, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView that is created by a for loop.  How would I pre-select an option?

```
arrayColour = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [substrings count]; i++)
    {
        //parse out each option (i)
        NSString* companyoption = [substrings objectAtIndex:i];
        //add as option to component
        [arrayColour addObject:companyoption];
    }
```

Lets assume I have a variable called StoredPicker and it has the value of the option they previously selected and I want to reselect that option when they come back to this view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this line of code and place your values,
by using this method you can achieve this one,

```
- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

ex:-  `[pickerView selectRow:n inComponent:0 animated:YES];`

EDIT:-
so try like this save the array object value in string and find out the array position by using below code and pass this integer value.

```
NSUInteger currentIndex = [itemArray indexOfObject:@"itemName"];
```

Comment: Thanks!  I should've mentioned that the picker is populated by web-services so the order of options could change.  If I'm storing the value of the option they selected is there a way auto-select the option that equals the value I have stored, rather than the numeric row they selected?

Comment: so in your case the options may be changed right means index may be changed ?

Comment: Exactly.  So I need to match the value stored with the possible options rather than storing the row count and then reselecting that row.

Comment: Very cool, so the currentIndex would be the "n" value passed in the line above?

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong here.  I have a stored variable called preValue which has the string of the option they previously picked.  I'm then calling NSUInteger currentIndex = [indexOfObject:preValue];
and then [pickerView selectRow:preValue inComponent:0 animated:YES]; but I seem to be getting errors on both lines.  Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: place [pickerView selectRow:currentIndex inComponent:0 animated:YES]; this line.

Comment: NSUInteger currentIndex = [yourarrayname indexOfObject:preValue];

Comment: So this is working great but it's not matching the string exactly.  For instance if the options are (Car A, Site 1, Site 2) and the user selects Site 2, it's prepopulating Site 1.  I think it may have to do with spaces?  Does this account for exact string matching?